# php for loops how to start again after else

Tags: loops, if-statement

I want to do something like this. Do you have ideas for this?

```
=== a ===

if( Something ){
=== b ===
{
else
{
go back to === a ===
}

Thanks.
```

Comment: Well we have `continue;`, though its not exactly a go back, it still run the afterthought statement. But I guess that might depend on language and how you are using the for loop.

Comment: Sounds like a recursive loop might work.

Answer (score 0):

It is usual `while` loop.

```
$something = false;
while (!$something) {
    //here are ====a==== actions
}
//here are b actions
```

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
while (true) {


  if( Something ){
     === b ===
  }
  else
  {
   === a ===
  }
  if (we're done) {
    break;
  }

}
```

Alternatively, you could use a proper condition in your `while` loop to exit.